# While trying to download the form data into plain text, I want the array data to be converted to a string and display in the text file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In the following code I am trying to make an array 'value' which has three parts 'str','com','val'. What i want is to display the data part in the downloaded text file in the form how its shown in the attached screenshot. I tried doing it in the below code but something is going miserably wrong and its showing data in some randomized fashion. Can anyone please help me achieve this.

[image: Sample output]

My o/p looks like below ss

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 const extra = {};
  
 const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
 const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
 const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
 const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
 const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
 const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
 const oiSCSI = document.querySelector('select[name="iSCSIip"]');
 const oTmp = document.querySelector('template');
  
  //Validating the input data and handling the changes made by the user
 const changehandler = function(e) {
   let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];
  
 if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
   else {
  if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
   }
  
 if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
  let fieldset = oTmp.content.cloneNode(true);
  oForm.insertBefore(fieldset, oProto.parentNode.nextSibling)
   } else {
   if (document.getElementById('extra')) {
   fieldset = document.getElementById('extra')
     fieldset.parentNode.removeChild(fieldset);
   }
    }
  
 if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
  else {
  if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }
  
//Enabling the protocol dropdown only if the controller is RAID
 if (this.name == 'controller') {
  if (this.value == 'RAID') oProto.disabled = false
 else oProto.disabled = true
   }
   

 if (this.name == 'protocol') {
  if (this.value == 'iSCSI') oiSCSI.disabled = false
 else oiSCSI.disabled = true
   }
 }
  
  
 const dialog = function(msg) {
   alert(msg);
   return false;
 }
  
 const savehandler = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let valid = true;

 /*
 if( oForm.test.value =='' || oForm.controller.value =='' || oForm.ip.value  == '' || oForm.chassis.value == '' || oForm.lo.value == '' || oForm.ro.value == ''){
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        return;
  }
 else if(oForm.extra_ip1.value == '' || oForm.extra_ip.value == '' || oForm.netmask_ip1.value == '' || oForm.netmask_ip.value == '' || oForm.gateway_ip1.value == '' || oForm.gateway_ip.value == '' ){
  alert("Please fill all the additonal required fields!");
        return;
 }
  
 const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
 if (ipformat.test(oForm.ip.value) == false) {
  return dialog('Invalid IP Address');
   }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.extra_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.extra_ip.value)== false ){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_IP Address');
 }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.netmask_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.netmask_ip.value)== false){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_Netmask Address');
 }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.gateway_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.gateway_ip.value)== false ){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_Gateway Address');
 }  
 */
 //Creating the data elements to be cpatured in the downloaded yaml file 
 let data = {

  "PDU": {
    //"PDU TEST": oForm.test.value,
    "PDU_IP": ['',oForm.ip.value,"#PDU IP"],
    "PDU_LEFT": ['',oForm.lo.value,"# left_outlet(s)"],
    "PDU_RIGHT":['',oForm.ro.value,"# right_outlet(s)"],
  }/*,
  "Controller": {
   
   //'Controller Type': oForm.controller.value,
   //'Protocol Type': oForm.protocol.value,
   //'Chasis Inputs': oForm.chassis.value,
   
   'iSCSI_IPs_A': oForm.iSCSIip1.value,
   'HBA_Ports':oForm.hba_ports1.value,
   'Netmask IP_A':oForm.extra_ip1.value,
   'MC_Netmask_A': oForm.netmask_ip1.value,
   'MC_Gateway_A':oForm.gateway_ip1.value,
   'MC_A': oForm.rbod_mc1.value,
   'SC_A':oForm.rbod_sc1.value,
   'FU_A':oForm.rbod_fu1.value,
   'EC_A':oForm.rbod_ec1.value,
   'Controller_ID#1': oForm.Controller_ID1.value,

   'iSCSI_IPs_B': oForm.iSCSIip2.value,
   'HBA_Ports':oForm.hba_ports.value,
   'Netmask IP_B':oForm.extra_ip.value,
   'MC_Netmask_B': oForm.netmask_ip.value,
   'MC_Gateway_B':oForm.gateway_ip.value,
   'MC_B': oForm.rbod_mc.value,
   'SC_B':oForm.rbod_sc.value,
   'FU_B':oForm.rbod_fu.value,
   'EC_B':oForm.rbod_ec.value,
   'Controller_ID#2': oForm.Controller_ID.value
  },*/
   };

//Crating the format of the data
 let payload = '';
 payload+= ' -  # UUT 0 configuration'+'\n -  # Chassis 0 configuration'+String.fromCharCode(10);
 const addToPayload = (object, whitespace) => {

  

 for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
  payload += whitespace + key + ':';
  const value = object[key];
  str=value[0];
  com=value[1];
  val=value[2];
  payload += whitespace + str + ':' + com + val;
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
   payload += String.fromCharCode(10);
   addToPayload(value, whitespace + '    ');
   } 
    else {
   payload += ' ' + value; //+ String.fromCharCode(10);
     }
  }
   }
   addToPayload(data, ' ' );

 /*var neNODE= document.createElement("h2");
 var nTNODE= document.createTextNode("text by JS");
 var ncNODE= document.createComment("comment");

 var comment = document.createComment("Comment");
 data.appendcomment
 */

//Converting the data into a yaml file and downloading it on button click
   const blob = new Blob([payload], {
  type: 'text/yaml'
   });
   var file =  oForm.test.value + "_" + oForm.protocol.value + "_UUT_Config" + '.yaml';
  
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   link.download = file;
  
   if (window.webkitURL != null) {
  link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
   } else {
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
   }
   link.click();
 }
  
  
 oCtrl.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
 oTest.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
 oSave.addEventListener('click', savehandler);
   })
//To Disable the text boxes based on the specific inputs i.e. HBA Ports and iSCSI IPs 
  function EnableDisableTextBox(abc) {
 var selectedValue = abc.options[abc.selectedIndex].value;
 var txt1 = document.getElementById("ip1");
 var txt2 = document.getElementById("ip2");

 var hbadisabled1 = document.getElementById("hba");
 var hbadisabled2 = document.getElementById("hba1");

 txt1.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? false : true;
 txt2.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? false : true;

 hbadisabled1.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? true : false;
 hbadisabled2.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? true : false;

 if (!txt1.disabled) {
  txt1.focus();
 }
 else if (!txt2.disabled){
  txt2.focus();
 }
 else if (!hbadisabled1.disabled) {
  hbadisabled1.focus();
 }
 else if (!hbadisabled2.disabled){
  hbadisabled2.focus();
 }

   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
  <!--<h1>User Information </h1>-->
  <style>
   html, html * {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-color: teal;
    font-family:calibri;
   }
   html{
      background : radial-gradient(rgba(33, 34, 34, 0.5),rgba(46, 45, 45, 0.5))
   }

   input[type=button],
   input[type=submit]{ 
    padding:1rem;
   }

  
   input[type=number]{
      width: 240px;
   height: 35px;
   font-size: 18px;
   } 

   input[type=text],
   textarea,
   select {
    font: 17px Calibri;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:teal
   }
   fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-style: initial;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
   }
   #extra{border:2px solid black; background:whitesmoke; border-radius:1rem;box-shadow:0 0 5px black;width:calc(100% - 24px);margin:auto;float:none;clear:both;text-indent: 50px;}
   #extra h6{margin:0}
   #extra style
   .invalid{border:2px solid red!important;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}
   
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <template>
   <fieldset id='extra'>
    <h6>Additional Details Required</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
     <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
     <option value='A'>A </select>
    <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips'  disabled="disabled" required />
    <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
    <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
    <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
    <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
    <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
    <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
    <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
    <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
<br>
<br>
    <label for='Controller_ID2'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller_ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
   <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" required />
   <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
   <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
   <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
   <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
   <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
   <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
   <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
   <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
    
   </fieldset>
  </template>
  
  
  
  <form name='myForm' method='POST' >
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Controller Type'><strong>Controller Type </strong></label>
    <select name='controller' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
     <option data-extra=true value='JBOD'>JBOD
     <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Test Type'><strong>Test Type</strong></label>
    <select name='test' required>
     <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
     <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
     <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
     <option data-extra=true value='Port Check' >Port Check
     <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic' >FW Generic
     <option data-extra=true value='JBOD Generic' >JBOD Generic
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <!-- insert templated additional details here -->
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Protocol Type'><strong> Protocol Type</strong></label>
    <select name='protocol' id="abc" onchange="EnableDisableTextBox(this);"  required>
     <option value=""> - Select The Protocol - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS</option>
     <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI</option>
     <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC</option>
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='IP Address'><strong> IP Address </strong></label>
    <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Left Outlets'><strong>Left Outlets </strong></label>
    <input type='text' name='lo' placeholder='Enter left outlets' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Right Outlets'><strong>Right Outlets</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='ro' placeholder='Enter right outlets' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Chasis Inputs</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='chassis' placeholder='Enter Number of Chasis'  required />
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <input type='button' name='save' value='Save data to file' />
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed width form? How is your output actually looking?

Comment: @SameerNaik Attached the screenshot of the o/p which i am getting. yes, i am using fixed width form